# Undesirable account linkage

Tags: github

I created two Github accounts. When I push into initial version into a repository of an account (xxxxx1780), the repository always shows the other account (xxxxx4386) as the initial commit. Should Github show xxxxx1780 instead of xxxxx4386? How to avoid showing the irrelevant xxxxx4386? Regards

[image]

Comment: the header bar you are referring to shows the last commit not the initial commit. So, the latest commit was done by xxxxx4386. Click on the `2 Commits` link under the button Code to see full commit history and xxxxx1780 as a user who made the initial commit.

Answer (score 0):

> the repository always shows the other account (xxxxx4386) as the initial commit.

The header bar you are referring to shows the last commit, not the initial commit.

[image]

So, the latest commit was done by xxxxx4386.

Click on the `2 Commits` link under the button **Code** to see full commit history and xxxxx1780 as a user who made the initial commit.